# Can a Hindu enter jannah?

Tags: tawheed, monotheism

This question was from a Hindu

That Islam is based on tawheed oness of Allah (god) if I believe that God has no image no idol not begotten doesn't have wife or child and believe in his uniqueness BUT don't accept prophet Muhammad saw and quran to be relevant to him, still do I have chance to enter jannah.

From my point of view he is correct because there are many hadiths which the PRIMORDIAL SIN in islam that puts you in hell for eternity is shirk and it will be not forgived otherwise you have chance....and there is hadiths which says a man came to prophet claimed that he has love for surah ikhlas then the prophet saw said your love for this surrah will enter you jannah ( indicating that to enter jannah aleast you have to be monotheist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person needs to believe in all the requirements of Islam to enter Jannah, including in the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ and the Quran, and anyone who dies while disbelieving in them will enter Jahannam forever.

> إن الذين يكفرون بالله ورسله ويريدون أن يفرقوا بين الله ورسله ويقولون نؤمن ببعض ونكفر ببعض ويريدون أن يتخذوا بين ذلك سبيلا
>
> أولئك هم الكافرون حقًّا وأعتدنا للكافرين عذابًا مهينًا
>
> Indeed, those who disbelieve in Allah and His messengers and wish to discriminate between Allah and His messengers and say, "We believe in some and disbelieve in others," and wish to adopt a way in between -
>
> Those are the disbelievers, truly. And We have prepared for the disbelievers a humiliating punishment.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:150-151](https://quran.com/4/150-152)</sup>

There are several other Quranic verses that imply the same e.g. [9:80](https://quran.com/9/80), [48:13](https://quran.com/48/13), [3:85](https://quran.com/3/85), [7:40](https://quran.com/7/40), [4:168-169](https://legacy.quran.com/4/168-169).